# Is there something like java's Character.digit(char ch, int radix) in c#?

Tags: c#, java, character

```
Character.digit(char ch, int radix)
```

Returns the numeric value of the character ch in the specified radix.

Is there an equivalent function in c#?

Answer (score 10):

I don't know of a direct equivalent
The closest match I can find is

```
Convert.ToInt32(string s, int baseFrom);
```

So you could convert your char to string then pass it in to the above function to get the int32 or Int16 or Byte or however you want to handle it :

```
char c = 'F';

int digit = Convert.ToInt32(c.ToString(),16);
```

Note - Convert will throw a FormatException if the char isn't a digit

Comment: Nice but sadly the base must be 2, 8, 10, or 16.

Answer (score 0):

If you work with hex characters you can do:

```
if (System.Uri.IsHexDigit(c)) {
  int v = System.Uri.FromHex(c);
}
```